# How to display the attribute of an RDF node using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf

I need to display the value of `rdf:resource` from the XML/RDF below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
    <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://example.com/randomurl">

        <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">example</skos:prefLabel>
        <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://example.com/randomurl"/>
        <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://example.com/randomurl"/>
        <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://example.com/randomurl"/>

    </skos:Concept>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I've tried, but can't figure out the correct path. It's probably something very small and facepalm worthy that I'm overlooking.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>    
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="//skos:prefLabel" /></h2>
    <br />    
    <xsl:for-each select="//skos:broader">
        Broader: <br />
    </xsl:for-each>        
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does go into the for-each loop and displays the correct amount of nodes that have `skos:narrower`, but when I try to get the `rdf:resource` with

```
<xsl:for-each select="//skos:broader">
    Broader: <xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource" /><br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

or a variation of the select, it just doesn't work. I've tried to find the solution by googling and searching here on Stack Overflow, but haven't managed to find one.

So what am I doing wrong?

Edit: following errors are generated:

> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): Undefined namespace prefix in [path] on line 57
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed in [path] on line 57
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): runtime error: file [path] line 25 element value-of in [path] on line 57
>
> Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): XPath evaluation returned no result. in

Comment: Do you really mean `skos:broader`?  You don't have any of those elements in your example XML.

Comment: Ah damnit. I thought I had changed that. Jep, I meant that one.

Comment: "It just doesn't work"...in what way?

Comment: It doesn't display anything on the w3schools.com try it. It does display errors on my server though, putting those in the post now.

Comment: Well that's precisely the problem. You're trying to use an undefined namespace. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Glad you've got it fixed, but bear in mind that there are many different equivalent serializations of the same RDF graph in XML (e.g. `<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://example.com/randomurl">` vs `<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/randomurl"><rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"></rdf:Description>`) so you may be wise to use a proper RDF API rather than simply treating it as XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that it's not working because you haven't declared the `rdf` namespace in your XSLT? When this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
      xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
      xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>
          <xsl:value-of select="//skos:prefLabel" />
        </h2>
        <br />
        <xsl:for-each select="//skos:broader">
          <xsl:text>Broader: </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="@rdf:resource"/>
          <br />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<html xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <body>
    <h2>example</h2><br>
    Broader: http://example.com/randomurl<br>
    Broader: http://example.com/randomurl<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did say that it was probably something small. I'm seriously facepalming now. It took you only a few minutes to figure out what I've been trying to fix for a few hours now. /hug

Comment: I'm just wondering now how the hell I could've missed that... Certainly not a mistake I'll soon make again.

Comment: :)  Glad to help. Sounds like the w3schools utility may be one of those tools that fails silently when the XSLT is invalid so remember to try it on a more reliable XSLT processor if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In your XSLT you had forgot to import the RDF namespace. Just add `xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"` to your XSLT. It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! JLRishe did answer before you though, so I chose his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark: when processing RDF/XML, the general rule is "do not use XML tools!" Is there a reason why you must use XSLT rather than dedicated RDF tools? Can you be certain that the RDF document you use with your XSLT will always have the same structure?

Let us imagine that I parse your RDF/XML document with an RDF API. Then I re-serialise it to RDF/XML. The result may very well be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
<skos:Concept rdf:about="http://example.com/randomurl">

    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">example</skos:prefLabel>
    <skos:broader>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/randomurl"/>
    </skos:broader>
    <skos:broader>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/randomurl"/>
    </skos:broader>
    <owl:sameAs>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/randomurl"/>
    </owl:sameAs>

</skos:Concept>
</rdf:RDF>
```

and your XSLT doesn't work anymore (although it's the same data, basically).